# How do I factor for irreducible in F2[x]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I need to factor  $x^7+x^6+x^2+x+1$ in $F_2[x]$. What are the steps?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion

, although i dont really get how it should work.

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion? In $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Eisenstein makes sense when you are working in $k[x]$, where $k$ is the quotient field of some UFD which is not a field itself. So, it never works for finite fields (because finite domains are fields). An elementary approach is that there are finitely many irreducible polynomials of degree $\le n$ in $\Bbb F_2[x]$.

Comment: Made a mistake. Fixed

Comment: Think about roots of this polynomial.

Comment: To check for the presence of a linear factor test whether it has zeros in $\Bbb{F}_2$. To check for the presence of an irreducible quadratic factor test whether it has a gcd with $x^3+1$. To check for the presence of a irreducible cubic factor test whether it has a gcd with $x^7+1$ (turns out there is one). Degree $n$ factors can be tested by calculating the gcd with $x^{2^n-1}+1$ - a task often less arduous than what it superficially appears. Of course, for degrees two and three you can just follow Michael's recipe (+1). Not unlike memorizing the small prime numbers!

Answer (score 3):

The hint.

1. Think about roots of this polynomial;
2. Prove that $x^2+x+1$ is an unique irreducible polynomial with degree two.
3. Prove that $x^3+x^2+1$ and $x^3+x+1$ they are unique irreducible polynomials with degree three.